# Duplicating object depending on presence of additional attributes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm making a project on Ruby-on-Rails. I have a sales CRUD. Sale has a "date" attribute. I need the system to duplicate sales after submitting form in case there are multiple dates selected.

How can I implement this?

The only way that comes to my mind is:

1. Create additional column :additional_dates in sales db table.
2. Add :additional_dates fields to the form.
3. Add after_save callback to Save model. Callback would duplicate
   sales depending on self.additional_dates and clean the column after
   that.

I know that this is far from the "Rails way". So it there any other more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create specific column in database for additional_dates. You can simply add additional_dates as an attribute in your Sale model.

`attr_accessor :additional_dates`

This let you interact with this attribute like others in your form or wherever.

Then, in your after_save or before_save callback, you can duplicate sale for each additional_dates.